# show the labels of Bokeh datetime axis in exact position of points

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm using the datetime axis of Bokeh. In the Bokeh data source, I have my x in numpy datetime format and others are y numbers. I'm looking for a way to show the label of the x datetimx axis right below the point. I want Bokeh to show **the exact datetime that I provided** via my data source, not some approximation! For instance, I provide 5:15:00 and it shows 5:00:00 somewhere before the related point.I plan to stream data to the chart every 1 hour, and I want to show 5 points each time. Therefore, I need 5 date-time labels. How can I do that? I tried `p.yaxis[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = 5` but it didn't help. Bokeh still shows as many number of ticks as it wants! Here is my code and result:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.palettes import Category10

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, plot_height=500)

data = {'x': 
        [np.datetime64('2019-01-26T03:15:10'),
      np.datetime64('2019-01-26T04:15:10'),
      np.datetime64('2019-01-26T05:15:10'),
      np.datetime64('2019-01-26T06:15:10'),
      np.datetime64('2019-01-26T07:15:10')],
    'A': [10,25,15,55,40],
    'B': [60,50,80,65,120],}

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

cl = Category10[3][1:]


r11 = p.line(source=source, x='x', y='A', color=cl[0], line_width=3)
r12 = p.line(source=source, x='x', y='B', color=cl[1], line_width=3)


p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
    seconds=["%H:%M:%S"],
    minsec=["%H:%M:%S"],
    minutes=["%H:%M:%S"],
    hourmin=["%H:%M:%S"],
    hours=["%H:%M:%S"],
    days=["%H:%M:%S"],
    months=["%H:%M:%S"],
    years=["%H:%M:%S"],
    )

p.y_range.start = -100
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.yaxis[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = 5
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi/2

show(p)
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the docs, `num_desired_ticks` is only a suggestion. If you want a ticks at specific locations that do not change, then you can use a [`FixedTicker`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#fixedticker), which can be set by plain list as convenience:

```
p.xaxis.ticker = [2, 3.5, 4]
```

For datetimes, you would pass the values as milliseconds since epoch.

If you want a fixed number of ticks, but the locations may change (i.e. because the range may change), then there is nothing built in to do that. You could make a [custom ticker extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html).